# why render of LineArt Modifier is jittery?

Tags: lineart

why render of LineArt Modifier is jittery?[image]

Comment: The easiest answer is that your image has too low resolution, which makes any image look pixelated.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nacly.png

here is 1920x1080

Comment: how did you resolve this?